# Getting Error Trying to Create AspectRatioThumbnail from Image I/O

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm trying to create an aspect ratio thumbnail from an `ALAsset` for pre iOS5 (the `ALAssetDefaultRepresentation aspectRatioThumbnail` wasn't implemented until ios5). I have the following code and it's giving me an error for some reason:

```
CGImageRef imref;
    NSURL* url = [self.photoAsset.defaultRepresentation url];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat,
                       (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform,
                       (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways,
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1024], kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize, nil];
    CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url, NULL);
    imref = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, (CFDictionaryRef) dictionary);
```

Specifically I'm getting:

```
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithURL CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -11.ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex image source parameter is nil
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I've put an answer on this question about how to generate a from an ALAsset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765340/generating-custom-thumbnail-from-alassetrepresentation/13941431#13941431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `url` that you are passing to create '`src`', 
check wether `url` is valid and there exists some image at this url.

Comment: I think the URL I'm retrieving isn't for the image, but for the asset itself. Any idea how to get the image URL?